# Wordpress Dropdown CSS not working

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm creating my own wordpress template and I've coded a jQuery drop down menu that works statically but now I'm trying to make it dynamic the css is messed up. The drop down works but the menu doesn't displaying correctly.

The main menu displays vertical instead of horizontal and the secondary menu is horizontal, instead of vertical. Also the orange type for the main menu isn't displaying.

Here's a working [static version](http://jsfiddle.net/5tzY3/)

I hope I'm explaining myself thoroughly, if you need any more info please let me know.

Here is my wordpress template code

```
<div class="box">
    <ul id="ldd_menu" class="ldd_menu">
        <li>
            <span>Menu</span>
            <!-- Increases to 510px in width-->
            <div class="sub_wrap">
                <div class="ldd_submenu">
                    <nav>
                        <li class="ldd_heading"></li>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'main_nav')); ?>
                    </nav>
                    <a class="ldd_subfoot" href="#"> Accessibility Link</a>
                </div>
           </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div></div>
```

Comment: your submenu lacks a new `<ul>` it shoudl be `<nav><ul><li>`

Comment: your HTML is not well-formed. Your `div` with class `sub_wrap` isn't closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect your code is not handling the output format of the wp_nav_menu method.  Now I am not sure of your exact version, but newer versions will out put like this.  So you will get extra div added in that you might not expect and the way the child menus are output may not be what you expect.  Also, as the previous people said your code is not quite right, missing some tags.

```
<div class="menu-id-container">
  <ul class="nav-menu" id="menu-id">
     <li class="..." id=".."><a href="#">LINK</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Child LINK1</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="..." id="..."><a href="#">LINK2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```